# How to access Attribute from a function within a decorator?

Tags: python, attributes, decorator

As in the title described, I want to access a attribute within a decorator. See the following example code:

```
def my_timer(orig_func):
    import time

    @wraps(orig_func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time() - t1
        print('{} ran in: {} sec'.format(orig_func, t2))
        return result

    return wrapper
```

As you can see I have the decorator function def my_timer(). And within it I have another decorator named def wrapper().
Im calling this decorator like this:

```
@my_logger
@my_timer
def fit(X_train, y_train):
    fitted = logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    fitted.train_y_predicted = fitted.predict(X_train)
    fitted.train_accuracy = np.mean(fitted.train_y_predicted.ravel() == y_train.ravel()) * 100
    fitted.train_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_train, fitted.train_y_predicted)
    
    return fitted
```

Now I need to call the attribute t2 from the @my_time decortator which is within the second decorator function def wrapper().

Furthemore Im calling the fit function in this step:

```
fitted = fit(X_train, y_train)
print()
print('Train Accuracy : ', fitted.train_accuracy,'\n')
print('Train Confusion Matrix :\n %s\n' % (fitted.train_confusion_matrix))
print()
```

and the displayed result is:

```
<function fit at 0x000001D3BCEB3F70> ran in: 0.024797439575195312 sec

Train Accuracy :  89.70149253731343 

Train Confusion Matrix :
 [[312  26]
 [ 43 289]]
```

And I need that time from this print: "<function fit at 0x000001D3BCEB3F70> ran in: 0.024797439575195312 sec" But I dont know how to get it.

Comment: ... *there is no attribute `t2`*. What are you talking about? The *local variable* `t2`? Also, `wrapper` is not a decorator, only `my_timer` is. `wrapper` is what is *returned* from your decorator*.

Comment: `runningtime = my_timer(fit)` inside `def fit` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes but i need the value from t2 which is within the def wrapper() function. 

I always get the error "AttributeError" x object has no attirbute "t2" and i cant fix it.

Comment: What are you doing, exactly? But again, **there is no such attribute**. Local variables are not attributes of a function. Generally, since they are local variables, they aren't accessible *outside the function*. That is why they are local variables. If you need some value from a function, you should typically return that value explicitly, or alternatively, mutate some globally (or nonlocally) accessible state -- although that approach is generally bad

Comment: Ah okay I understand. I wrote it wrong. Is there a way that i access this variable or to get this input? Im tracking the time and need it to safe in a next step.

Comment: Can I somehow access the return value "result" form the def wrapper function inside of the function def my_timer()?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. You access the result by calling the decorated function... `result = fit(whatever, whatever)`. But you seem to want access to it *inside* `fit`, which fundamentally doesn't make sense

Comment: im calling the fit function in a next step. And after this step i want to safe the tracked time.

Comment: *what step*? What are you talking about? Just show us exactly, don't give vague descriptions. In any case, you are simply printing the time, you never do anything else with it like return it, so that time that was in `t2` is garbage collected after the function returns.

Comment: I update the question. Wait. And I want that print to be stored in a variable btw. to be returned, that i can use it.

Comment: Again, **you must return the value you need**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change a little bit your wrapper to add the time to run your function such that :

```py
def my_timer(orig_func):
    import time

    @wraps(orig_func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time() - t1
        print('{} ran in: {} sec'.format(orig_func, t2))
        return result, t2

    return wrapper
```

and use it like so

```
@my_logger
@my_timer
def fit(X_train, y_train):
    fitted = logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    fitted.train_y_predicted = fitted.predict(X_train)
    fitted.train_accuracy = np.mean(fitted.train_y_predicted.ravel() == y_train.ravel()) * 100
    fitted.train_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_train, fitted.train_y_predicted)
    
    return fitted

fitted, t = fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

This way, you add `t2` to the output of your function by using the decorator. Note that I removed

```
runningtime = my_timer(fit)
```

as it will just create a function that never gets called (thanks [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) )

Comment: "as it will just keep calling your fit function (for ever ? )" It won't, it just returns a new function, that doesn't get called, it doesn't make any sense so it should be removed anyway

Comment: Yes true ! I'll edit my answer, I was thinking to ```runningtime = my_timer(fit(X_train, y_train))``` while writing

Comment: so, the `@my_timer def fit(...)...` syntax is just sugar for `fit = my_timer(fit)` after `def fit()...`

Comment: Well his answer worked. Thank you guys for your time !:)